# Find elements which have first character as number and second is string in Array of String

Tags: javascript, arrays

From `array` of strings find elements which have first character as number and second is string ?

Comment: Have you tried something that is not working?

Comment: This question sounds like "I don't feel like doing my homework so I'm throwing it here and let those geeks solve it for me". Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You can't disable comments. And especially if that is your first question here, you are expected to read the community guidelines on how to ask a question first

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is the example you want?

```js
const arr = ['6a', '12', 'jk'];
const regex = /^\d[a-zA-Z].*$/;
console.log(arr.filter(str => regex.test(str)));
```